# How to change the attribute name with historical data in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

If I want to change the name of a certain attribute, or add an attribute in Apache IoTDB, what should I do if there is already a large amount of historical data stored in the previous attribute name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ALTER timeseries root.turbine.d1.s1 RENAME tag1 TO newTag1` statement to rename a tag or attribute in Apache IoTDB, and it will not affect the storage of historical data.